# How to detect Ambiguous and Invalid DateTime in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst

When dealing with local `DateTime` values provided by a user, it's quite possible to have a time that is either invalid or ambiguous, due to Daylight Saving Time transitions.

In other languages and frameworks, there are often methods such as `isAmbiguous` and `isValid`, on some representation of the time zone.  For example in .NET, there is [`TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396403.aspx) and [`TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime.aspx).

Plenty of other time zone implementations have similar methods, or functionality to address this concern.  For example, in Python, the [pytz library](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) will throw an `AmbiguousTimeError` or `InvalidTimeError` exception that you can trap.

PHP has excellent time zone support, but I can't seem to find anything to address this.  The closest thing I can find is [DateTimeZone::getTransitions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php).  That provides the raw data, so I can see that some methods could be written on top of this.  But do they exist already somewhere?  If not, can anyone provide a good implementation?  I would expect them to work something like this:

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
echo $tz->isValidTime(new DateTime('2013-03-10 02:00:00'));       # false
echo $tz->isAmbiguousTime(new DateTime('2013-11-03 01:00:00'));   # true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I 'm not aware of any existing implementations and I haven't had cause to use advanced date/time features such as these as yet, so here is a clean room implementation.

To enable the syntax illustrated in the question we are going to extend `DateTimeZone` as follows:

```
class DateTimeZoneEx extends DateTimeZone
{
    const MAX_DST_SHIFT = 7200; // let's be generous

    // DateTime instead of DateTimeInterface for PHP < 5.5
    public function isValidTime(DateTimeInterface $date);

    public function isAmbiguousTime(DateTimeInterface $date);
}
```

To keep distracting details from cluttering the implementation, I am going to assume that the `$date` arguments have been created with the proper time zone; this is in contrast to the example code given in the question.

That is to say, the correct result will not be produced by this:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZoneEx('America/New_York');
echo $tz->isValidTime(new DateTime('2013-03-10 02:00:00'));
```

but instead by this:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZoneEx('America/New_York');
echo $tz->isValidTime(new DateTime('2013-03-10 02:00:00', $tz));
```

Of course since `$tz` is already known to the object as `$this`, it should be easy to extend the methods so that this requirement is removed. In any case, making the interface super user friendly is out of the scope of this answer; going forward I will focus on the technical details.

#### `isValidTime`

The idea here is to use [`getTransitions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) to see if there are any transitions around the date/time we are interested in. `getTransitions` will return an array with either one or two elements; the timezone situation for the "begin" timestamp will always be there, and another element will exist if a transition occurs shortly after it. The value of `MAX_DST_SHIFT` is small enough that there is no chance of getting a second transition/third element.

Let's see the code:

```
public function isValidTime(DateTime $date)
{
    $ts = $date->getTimestamp();
    $transitions = $this->getTransitions(
        $ts - self::MAX_DST_SHIFT,
        $ts + self::MAX_DST_SHIFT
    );

    if (count($transitions) == 1) {
        // No DST changes around here, so obviously $date is valid
        return true;
    }

    $shift = $transitions[1]['offset'] - $transitions[0]['offset'];

    if ($shift < 0) {
        // The clock moved backward, so obviously $date is valid
        // (although it might be ambiguous)
        return true;
    }

    $compare = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $this);

    return $compare->modify("$shift seconds")->getTimestamp() != $ts;
}
```

The final point of the code depends on the fact that PHP's date functions calculate timestamps for invalid date/times as if wall clock time had not shifted. That is, the timestamps calculated for `2013-03-10 02:30:00` and `2013-03-10 03:30:00` will be identical on the New York timezone.

It's not difficult to see how to take advantage of this fact: create a new `DateTime` instance equal to the input `$date`, then shift it forward *in wall clock time terms* an amount equal to the DST shift in seconds (it is imperative that DST not be taken into account to make this adjustment). If the timestamp of the result (here the DST rules come into play) is equal to the timestamp of the input, then the input is an invalid date/time.

#### `isAmbiguousTime`

The implementation is quite similar to `isValidTime`, only a few details change:

```
public function isAmbiguousTime(DateTime $date)
{
    $ts = $date->getTimestamp();
    $transitions = $this->getTransitions(
        $ts - self::MAX_DST_SHIFT, 
        $ts + self::MAX_DST_SHIFT);

    if (count($transitions) == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    $shift = $transitions[1]['offset'] - $transitions[0]['offset'];

    if ($shift > 0) {
        // The clock moved forward, so obviously $date is not ambiguous
        // (although it might be invalid)
        return false;
    }

    $shift = -$shift;
    $compare = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $this);
    return $compare->modify("$shift seconds")->getTimestamp() - $ts > $shift;
}
```

The final point depends on another implementation detail of PHP's date functions: when asked to produce the timestamp for an ambiguous date/time, PHP produces the timestamp of the first (in absolute time terms) occurrence. This means that *the timestamps of the latest ambiguous time and the earliest non-ambiguous time for a given DST change will differ by an amount larger than the DST offset* (specifically, the difference will be in the range [`offset + 1`, `2 * offset`], where `offset` is an absolute value).

The implementation takes advantage of this by again doing a "wall clock shift" forward and checking the timestamp difference between the result and the input `$date`.

**[See the code in action](http://ideone.com/orPTCp)**.

Comment: Very nice and complete answer! I wish all answers were so well thought out and described! I will award the bounty as soon as StackOverflow lets me.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Bounty awarded. Thanks again!