# PHP DateTime::format('I') inaccuracy bug?

Tags: php, timezone, format, dst

I'm wondering if this is a bug, or if I missed something.

While creating a method to isolate the timestamp when DST switches from on to off and vice versa, I noticed a potential bug with DateTime::format('I'). When DST ends and the time is switched backwards one hour, DateTime::format('I') reports the switch one hour too late.

In the 'America/Montreal' timezone, we can look at these timestamps when DST ends:

1414904400, Sun, 02 Nov 2014 01:00:00 -0400  (DST on)
1414908000, Sun, 02 Nov 2014 01:00:00 -0500  (DST off)
1414911600, Sun, 02 Nov 2014 02:00:00 -0500  (DST off)

Notice the DST ends on the second timestamp when 01:00:00 is repeated.

But, using DateTime::format('I') the ending is reported on the third timestamp.

```
$timezone = new DateTimezone('America/Montreal');
$datetime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
$datetime->setTimestamp(1414904400);
echo $datetime->format('I');
$datetime->setTimestamp(1414908000);
echo $datetime->format('I');
$datetime->setTimestamp(1414911600);
echo $datetime->format('I');
```

returns 110 (should be 100)

If we use date('I') we get the correct answer.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
echo date('I', 1414904400);
echo date('I', 1414908000);
echo date('I', 1414911600);
```

returns 100 (as expected)

---

When DST begins DateTime::format('I') works fine, it only seems to fail when DST ends.

Also, I have tested this for a few different years in a few different timezones, but I have no idea of the depth of this potential bug. Much more testing is needed.

Anyone know what this is?

Comment: If you really believe that this is a bug in PHP's DateTime implementation, then why not raise it as a bug on https://bugs.php.net/ - Looks like it might have already been raised - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65811

Comment: Good point, I will. I searched the web and couldn't find anything on it, but then I figured the bug must be too common to have been missed. I guess I was doubting myself.

Comment: #65811 definitely seems to be the same issue that you've described, looks like nobody has addressed it yet.... if your C is any good, try taking a look at the source code

Comment: No, it's not the same issue. What I'm getting is the wrong result for whether DST is on or off, what that bug describes is the time being wrong. He seems to be getting the correct results for DST status.

Comment: It looks like that modifying the timestamp on a `DateTime` with timezone set up goes wrong. Even calling `$dt->getTimestamp()` immediately after setting it returns the wrong value. A workaround (until the bug is fixed) is this `$dt = new DateTime('@1414908000');
$dt->setTimezone($tz);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O (I) U');`

Comment: Note that the `O` format code also returns incorrect results like `I`

Comment: After more testing, Peter van der Wal was correct. The whole problem is that the first timestamp (1414904400) remains and the second one is never set. So, anything in format will return the info for the first timestamp. It seems setTimestamp() does not like it when DST ends and the time falls back one hour. When I try to change to other timestamps it's fine. Peter's solution above works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While creating a method to isolate the timestamp when DST switches from on to off and vice versa ...

That method already exists as `DateTimeZone::GetTransitions`.  [Documentation here.](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php)

You may also be interested in the related problem of determining whether a particular date/time is within a transition period, which is described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18793850/634824).

Comment: Thank you. I tested the GetTransitions method and it works nicely. You're right, it solves my problem, so my code above is now irrelevant. Thanks for your help.

You didn't really answer my question (about the bug), but you solved my overall problem, so I guess I'll mark your answer as being accepted.

Comment: Peter's response in the question comments addresses the bug, and I concur with the findings.  Glad this helped though.