# Choose the preferred offset during a DateTime DST overlap

Tags: php, datetime, dst

In time-zones observing Daylight Saving Time, the clock typically:

- moves forward during transition from *winter* to *summer*
- is set back during transition from *summer* to *winter*

For example, in the `Europe/Paris` time-zone, the UTC offset changes from `+02:00` to `+01:00` during the transition from *summer* to *winter*, at `3:00 AM` on the last Sunday of the month of October.

In other words:

At `3:00 AM` (`+02:00`) on `2014-10-26`, clocks are set back to `2:00 AM` (`+01:00`).

Which means that creating a `DateTime` for `2014-10-26` at `02:30 AM` in the `Europe/Paris` time-zone is ambiguous, as it can represent either:

- `2014-10-26T02:30+01:00` (timestamp `1414287000`)
- `2014-10-26T02:30+02:00` (timestamp `1414283400`)

Java's [ZonedDateTime documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) explains this problem very well, and their API offers a way to choose the preferred offset if needed.

In PHP however, it seems that this ambiguity is resolved by choosing arbitrarily the *winter* time:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2014-10-26T02:30', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // 2014-10-26T02:30:00+0100
echo $dt->getTimestamp(); // 1414287000
echo $dt->getOffset(); // 3600
echo $dt->getTimeZone->getName(); // Europe/Paris
```

*(By arbitrarily, I mean that I could not find any documentation about it).*

**Is there a way to choose the preferred offset when creating a `DateTime` from a date and time that fall within a DST overlap for the given time-zone?**

Or in other words:

**How can I create a `DateTime` object that would exhibit the following characteristics:**

```php
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // 2014-10-26T02:30:00+0200
echo $dt->getTimestamp(); // 1414283400
echo $dt->getOffset(); // 7200
echo $dt->getTimeZone->getName(); // Europe/Paris
```

That is, an object representing this date/time in the `Europe/Paris` time-zone in **summer** time?

Answer (score 2):

First, consider that there is [a known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63442) in PHP that will affect you here.  Consider:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2014-10-26T02:30', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . " (" . $dt->getTimeStamp() . ")\n";

$dt->setTimeStamp($dt->getTimeStamp() - 3600);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . " (" . $dt->getTimeStamp() . ")\n";
```

Output:

```
2014-10-26T02:30:00+0100 (1414287000)
2014-10-26T02:30:00+0100 (1414287000)
```

Even though you adjusted the timestamp back an hour to reflect summer time, PHP erroneously advanced it to the winter time position.

You can work around this *for display purposes* by using UTC as an intermediary.

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
$dt = new DateTime('2014-10-26T02:30', $tz);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . " (" . $dt->getTimeStamp() . ")\n";

$ts = $dt->getTimeStamp() - 3600;
$dt = new DateTime("@$ts", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt->setTimeZone($tz);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . " (" . $dt->getTimeStamp() . ")\n";
```

Output:

```
2014-10-26T02:30:00+0100 (1414287000)
2014-10-26T02:30:00+0200 (1414287000)
```

Note that even though the wrong timestamp is returned (it should be 1414283400), it does retain the desired summer-time offset of +0200.

Now, lets tackle the problem of knowing when to apply this.  We'll examine the transitions and use that to decide whether or not to subtract an hour.

```php
// set up the original input values
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
$dt = new DateTime('2014-10-26T02:30', $tz);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";

// check for a transition +/- an hour from the current time stamp
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
$transitions = $tz->getTransitions($ts - 3600, $ts + 3600);
if (count($transitions) > 1) {

    // see if we are moving backwards, creating the ambiguity
    $shift = $transitions[1]['offset'] - $transitions[0]['offset'];
    if ($shift < 0)
    {
        // apply the difference in offsets to move back to summer time
        $ts = $ts + $shift;
        $dt = new DateTime("@$ts", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $dt->setTimeZone($tz);
    }
}

echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2014-10-26T02:30:00+0100
2014-10-26T02:30:00+0200
```

You may also wish to read [this related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18409405/634824).