# PHP strtotime and DST

Tags: php, strtotime, dst

I have an application where users input times/dates, which are then converted via strtotime() into Unix timestamps (the users set their own timezones).This usually works quite well; strtotime() even manages to convert a time such as 2:15 AM, March 9, 2014 into a timestamp (which corresponds with the timestamp that would be returned if the user input "3:15 AM March 9, 2014").

**However, say a user wants to enter a time during the morning of November 2, 2014 - specifically, between 2:00 and 3:00.  Is there an element that users can add to to specify *which* time will be used?**

For example, if a user passes '2:15 AM November 2, 2014' through strtotime(), the result is a UNIX timestamp corresponding to the "second" 2:15 on that date.

**How would one specify the "first" 2:15?**

Comment: I suggest you use the `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes instead of `strtotime()`

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but I'm not sure how that would be useful to users?  I realized that my initial post was somewhat unclear, so I've edited it.  Right now, the application accepts input from users such as '2:15 AM November 2, 2014.'  Is there a string that the *user* (not the coder, as I incorrectly wrote in my OP) can enter to tell the program *which* "2:15" they intended?  Or is this something that I'd have to use DateTime for anyway?  Again, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: There is basically no solution to this. There simply are two 2:15am on November 2nd. You simply don't do anything during that time, unless you don't mind possibly having to wait an hour. That's why the switchover happens in the middle of the night on a weekend to reduce the issues this causes to a minimum. There's no official solution to this ambiguity anywhere in the real world I'm aware of.

Comment: @deceze what FUD.  Just because *you* aren't aware of a solution doesn't mean one doesn't exist.

Comment: @Matt Your solution is to futz with the timezone? Well, of course, if you have enough information about the problem to do that, you can always add or subtract an hour by doing that. It still means that within one timezone, there are *two* 2:15am and no official notation to disambiguate those two.

Comment: @deceze - There are two instances in a *time zone*, but only one instance in a *time zone offset*.  In other words, there is only one 2:15 EST and only one 2:15 EDT, but both exist within ET as defined by `America/New_York`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a time zone offset or abbreviation along with the string to parse, and it will *usually* select the correct timestamp.

For example, say you are working with the US Eastern time zone (`"America/New_York")`, you could include an offset like this:

```
strtotime('2:15 AM November 2, 2014 -0400')  // 1414908900
strtotime('2:15 AM November 2, 2014 -0500')  // 1414912500
```

Or by abbreviation:

```
strtotime('2:15 AM November 2, 2014 EDT')  // 1414908900
strtotime('2:15 AM November 2, 2014 EST')  // 1414912500
```

Now the reason I said *"usually"* is because time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous.  Checking [Wikipedia's list of time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), there are 2 different interpretations of "EST".  Some are much worse, such as 5 different interpretations of "CST".  In general, it's not good to rely on time zone abbreviations for *input*.  Stick with offsets and you'll be fine.

Of course, you still need to know which offsets are applicable to which time zones.  In PHP, you can use [`timezone_offset_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) for this.

You might also be interested in [this question, and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18409405/634824), which can help you determine if your input time is invalid or ambiguous.  You could then prompt the user accordingly, and (in the ambiguous case) ask them to choose between one of the two possible offsets.